# Why the button with a fixed height can't align perfect with other buttons when there's something in it but not using up its height?

Tags: html, css

There are 6 buttons, the second one has something inside. But I defined all the buttons a fixed height and the inside content is not using up the room at all. Why it's still not in the expected position?

Please take a look at this simple code:

```css
button {height:60px;width:50px;border:1px solid #000;box-sizing:border-box}
button span {display:block;color:grey; font-size:9px}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2<span>2.1</span></button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
```

Comment: remove `display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `<br>` tag, which indents downwards and therefore offsets your button. If you need to solve this problem, then I made such a solution for you, using `position: absolute`.

```css
button {
  height:60px;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  box-sizing:border-box
}

button span {
  color:grey; 
  font-size:9px;

  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-45%, 25%);
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2<br><span>2.1</span></button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
```

Comment: Hi, though it solves, the problem still exists without <br>. So it's not about <br>, right? I've updated my question.

Comment: besides, your solution would make the content not in the center, vertically.

Comment: because you wrote `display:block` for `button span`. In fact, your problem can be solved with `flexbox`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not the `br` tag (which you have already edited out), it's the fact that `button` by default (user agent styles) has `display: inline-block`, which means that your succession of buttons forms a textual **line**, it sits ***in line***.

If you want to stick with that, you need to make sure all your buttons in that **line** align vertically, so use `vertical-align`:

```css
button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button span {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2<span>2.1</span></button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are putting  br  tag inside the second button which means  new line.

So change it to (remove br tag)

```
<button>2<span>2.1</span></button>
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/z1tao30g](https://jsfiddle.net/z1tao30g/)

Answer (score -2):

here you are:

html:

```
<button>1<br><span class="visnon">.</span></button>
<button>2<br><span>2.1</span></button>
<button>3<br><span class="visnon">.</span></button>
<button>4<br><span class="visnon">.</span></button>
<button>5<br><span class="visnon">.</span></button>
<button>6<br><span class="visnon">.</span></button>
```

css:

```
button {height:60px;width:50px;border:1px solid #000;box-sizing:border-box}
button span {color:grey; font-size:9px}
.visnon{visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: An explanation of _why_ this answers the question would make your answer a bit more useful. Otherwise, this isn't much more than a code-dump.

Comment: sorry, i just added <br><span>.</span> to all of them and then i maked them invisible to user dont see that "." , now all of them have one dot under the number and it is invisible